# How to Setup HA for Kubernetes on CentOS, Runing 1 Master 2 Worker already using kubeadm

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

I have successfully setup Normal Cluster, Now when I am trying for HA setup following doc https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/high-availability/

Here after copying etcd.yaml file in /etc/kubernetes/manifest I see 3 etcd container inside my cluster

`default         etcd-server-kuber-poc-app1                  1/1       Running   1          2d
default         etcd-server-kuber-poc-app2                  1/1       Running   72         20h
kube-system     etcd-kuber-poc-app1                         1/1       Running   4          13d`

But when I check logs for any etcd pods I see error like

> 2017-11-15 08:53:25.398815 E | discovery: error #0: x509: failed to
>   load system roots and no roots provided
>
> 2017-11-15 08:53:25.398907 I | discovery: cluster status check: error
>   connecting to https://discovery.etcd.io, retrying in 18h12m16s

Seems like missing certs for them

But I am not sure which certs to create and where to place

Yaml Content

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: etcd-server
spec:
  hostNetwork: true
  containers:
  - image: gcr.io/google_containers/etcd:3.0.17
    name: etcd-container
    command:
    - /usr/local/bin/etcd
    - --name
    - NODE-1
    - --initial-advertise-peer-urls
    - http://10.127.38.18:2380
    - --listen-peer-urls
    - http://10.127.38.18:2380
    - --advertise-client-urls
    - http://10.127.38.18:4001
    - --listen-client-urls
    - http://127.0.0.1:4001
    - --data-dir
    - /var/etcd/data
    - --discovery
    - https://discovery.etcd.io/9458bcd46077d558fd26ced5cb9f2a6a
    ports:
    - containerPort: 2380
      hostPort: 2380
      name: serverport
    - containerPort: 4001
      hostPort: 4001
      name: clientport
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/etcd
      name: varetcd
    - mountPath: /etc/ssl
      name: etcssl
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /usr/share/ssl
      name: usrsharessl
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /var/ssl
      name: varssl
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /usr/ssl
      name: usrssl
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /usr/lib/ssl
      name: usrlibssl
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /usr/local/openssl
      name: usrlocalopenssl
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/openssl
      name: etcopenssl
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/pki/tls
      name: etcpkitls
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /var/etcd/data
    name: varetcd
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/ssl
    name: etcssl
  - hostPath:
      path: /usr/share/ssl
    name: usrsharessl
  - hostPath:
      path: /var/ssl
    name: varssl
  - hostPath:
      path: /usr/ssl
    name: usrssl
  - hostPath:
      path: /usr/lib/ssl
    name: usrlibssl
  - hostPath:
      path: /usr/local/openssl
    name: usrlocalopenssl
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/openssl
    name: etcopenssl
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/pki/tls
    name: etcpkitls
```

So 2 Issue

1) How to Create Certs?

2) Where to Keep them?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can make kubeadm cluster as HA.  your option is to recreate the cluster with kubespray https://github.com/kubespray/kubespray-cli tool, this will create the certificate with all the nodes.

for step by step instruction follow Kubernetes The Hard Way https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way

Comment: Thanks for sharing links "Kubernetes The Hard Way" seems more specific to GCE
kubespray  seems one of the tool to play with but they specified need 8 VM for clustering 
I have 5 VM and Planning for 3 Master and 2 Worker
not sure why its mentioned to have 3 etcd servers seprately

Comment: https://get.k8s.io/

I was thinking to recreate my cluster from above Script for CentOS 7 VM

But not sure what option to run this scripts with

is below onw is fine 

#  Vagrant (local virtual machines)
#   * export KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=vagrant; wget -q -O - https://get.k8s.io | bash

Comment: first we need to create the ansible configuration file. use something like this to create the config file. `kubespray prepare --nodes node1[ansible_ssh_host=10.99.21.1] node2[ansible_ssh_host=10.99.21.2] node3[ansible_ssh_host=10.99.21.3] `